# The application has lag after creating build but not in unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, stereo-3d, zspace

I am building a app for Zspace device in unity3D. So I created a game which was able to run normally in Editor as well as normal windows Build. But the real problem started coming when I created a stereo enabled standalone for Zspace device; which uses **opengl 2.1**. The package is used is **Zcore 4.0** and U**nity 5.3.3**. The machine is Zspace 200.
I have run normal builds on same machine without stereo which runs smoothly. But when I changed the build settings the game FPS fell to 3-5. As far as I can make out by debugging this is related to **Skinned Mesh Renderer** of my animating model. To confirm this I disabled SMR and ran the application without any lag. I have profiled and found "Shadows.RenderJobDir" and "Batch.CmdDrawDynamics" is taking too much of the time. Also as you can see in the image it takes 784ms to render which is really high. I am not sure anymore how to solve the problem. I would really appriciate if anyone can point me in right direction.

[image: Profile Image 1]
[image: Profile Image 2]

[image: Profiler Image with normal Just Single Model SMR in scene]

Comment: Also can anyone can create a tag Zspace for this question? As this tag is yet not available to add :)

Comment: Is there anything of interest in the logs?

Comment: try opening Window > Lighting and make sure you don't have global illumination or stuff like that on. Also in build settings have you tried setting dynamic batching to on? In Edit > Project Settings > Quality > for zSpace platform select Fastest.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Nope i haven't seen anything specific regarding lag in the logs

Comment: @NikaKasradze yup i have changed the lighting settings, the dynamic batching. The only little difference i noted was that when i changed the quality to fastest I the FPS increased but still the lag was there when the SMR was turned on in the scene.

Comment: what shader do u use? and how big is your mesh?

Comment: i use legacy/diffuse shader and my model is approx 3mb file with approx 100k polygon count.

Comment: Stop the app then enable **Deep Profile** in the Profiler, play and take a screenshot of the deep object with the highest cpu value. Also do you mean 100k polygon per model?

Comment: @Programmer I checked with the deep profile for the model with SMR in new project and it takes highest value for culling in camera render. And the 100k polygon count is for only one model which is enabled only once in the scene. When it is enabled the game lags like anything. The above profiler image is where you can see the huge spikes is where it is lagging in the new project where I have just the model in scene and nothing else.

Comment: No help on this, anyone? My build on iPad is 5 FPS because "Shadows.RenderJobDir" takes up as much as more than half the CPU time :(